# How can there be 0 volts difference and yet I can feel electrical tingle?

Tags: grounding, mains, appliances

While the background for this question is quite practical and probably off-topic for this site, what I'm asking here for is *why this happens* and not how to fix it. I want to understand the electrical forces involved, not just get a quick fix.

With that out of the way.

Grounding. I've never understood it. It always acts in mysterious ways.

Case in point: my latest adventures with trying to install a dishwasher.

First of all I live in a flat in an older house which has no grounding in outlets. This is Latvia, so 230V/50Hz. After installing the dishwasher I realized that when I touch the sink and the dishwasher at the same time, I can feel a noticeable and unpleasant tingle. It's not the full 230V, not even close, but still noticeable enough to be startling.

I tried measuring the voltage difference with my trusty cheap old multimeter, but it came out as 0V... or at times even -1V, which makes no sense. Putting the multimeter directly into an outlet shows around 230V as expected, so it's not broken. Measuring between the plug pins and the body shows that they aren't connected, so there is no broken insulation.

I also have one of those indicator screwdrivers. When I touch the sink or the dishwasher individually with it, it doesn't glow. But when I touch my other hand to the other object, it glows.

Weirder yet - if I plug in an extension cord which has grounding, into an outlet that doesn't (it physically doesn't have grounding connectors), and then connect the grounding pin, myself, screwdriver, and the sink - it glows! And if I unplug the extension cord, it stops glowing.

The same effect exists between desktop computer cases and the centralized heating pipes/radiators. I've even noticed it with my old laptop when it's connected via a power adapter. And that adapter only gives out 19V!

To try and combat this I brought in a cable from outside my apartment which is connected to a grounded breaker/meter box. Or at least that's what the rumour says. At the very least I can confirm it's connected to the neutral.

Measuring between that ground and the sink now gives me around 6V... and also a tingle. The screwdriver behaves the same as before.

Slightly worse, since my oven/stovetop are also connected to the same outlet, they too have now started to give a tingle when touching them at the same time as the sink. So, basically I would be better off without the grounding in that outlet.

I'm lost. How can there be such a noticeable electrical tingle, when the voltage measured is 0V? Why does the screwdriver not glow when I touch it to the sink, but starts to glow if my other hand touches a disconnected wire - but only if that wire is close to electrified wires?

Comment: Is your multimeter doing average or RMS? I wouldn't trust the multimeter showing 0V based on your experience.

Comment: You are measuring between what and what? With AC or DC meter?

Comment: @JYelton - What's a RMS and what does it eat in the winter? :D I really don't know, and those letters don't appear on it.

Comment: @EugeneSh. - I'm measuring AC, and I've measured between anything involved. Mostly between the surfaces that give me a tingle when I touch them both.

Comment: You may want to research https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/35944/2028

Comment: Post a photo of your multimeter with the exact setting you are using.

Comment: @JYelton - if those answers are correct, then True RMS measurements are apparently very expensive. Mine cost like $10, so I'm pretty sure it doesn't do that. That said, the answers also said that for mains power (which is close to a true sinusoid) the measurements should be very close to the truth even with the cheaper methods.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Well, here you are: https://photos.app.goo.gl/rh2GefknDuj2A3hv7

Comment: @EugeneSh. - Note that if I want to measure full 230V I need to set it to "ACV - 500", otherwise it tops out. But in this case it measures 0 in all cases.

Comment: @JYelton Aren't all the meters on ACV setting measuring RMS?

Comment: @EugeneSh. No. Cheaper ones measure peak and assume it's a sine-wave so multiply it by 0.707. True RMS ones should be calculating it numerically with samples applied to the RMS equation.

Comment: @DKNguyen Oh, well, it still gives RMS for sinusoidal voltage. I meant if there is any case where it will be measuring average, which would not make sense.

Comment: I would purchase a portable GFCI (I'm not sure what they are called in Latvia). These can be placed between a wall socket and the cord for a device/appliance. If the GFCI does not trip, then presumably there is not sufficient leakage on that circuit to be a danger. I would try all your devices/appliances to see if any are leaking a dangerous amount of current to ground. Probably not, since you are still alive, but I would do so for safety. If one of the appliances should trip the GFCI, then you will need to take some steps to ensure safety. What steps depends on details.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy - I've GFCIs installed for my entire apartment. The tingle doesn't seem to trip them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Devices with earthed mains plug such as computers and dishwashers have a mains input filter, with so called Y capacitors from Live to Earth and Neutral to Earth.

If you don't plug the device into Earthed mains socket like you are supposed to, all parts that should be Earthed are floating and the filter Y capacitors create a capacitive divider, so the parts that should be Earthed has capacitively coupled half mains voltage of 115 VAC (assuming 230 VAC mains) on all metal surfaces.

The current drive ability of one device is quite limited but still you can feel it.

Since it is the device that now drives the Earth pin on the extension cord it will energize all other Earthed devices on the extension cord too, even if those have no filter Y capacitors inside them. If the other devices do have the filter Y capacitors, then each device adds up and the Earth pin is driven more strongly.

Kitchen is one place there really should be Earthed sockets. Even really old houses (40 years old or mode) have had Earthed sockets in the kitchen and bathroom in many countries. Consider upgrading the electrical system for safety.

Many devices have a statement on them or in the manual that they must be connectes to an Earthed outlet. This is one reason why. Water and electricity are also a dangerous combination so consider having a grounded socket for it.

Comment: I sort of did add ground to it - as much as was possible anyway - but that didn't seem to help. The "ground" comes from the riser shaft in the stairwell of my condo. The metal box out there houses the breakers and the meters, and rumour has it that it's grounded. At the very least I can confirm that it's connected to the neutral. Whether it's actually grounded, I don't know. And there seems to be around a 6V difference between that and the plumbing.

Comment: If you have some voltage "leaking" on to the appliance body, grounding it will probably trip the fuses.

Comment: @EugeneSh. - That's another one of my worries that I haven't even voiced in this question. I could just connect them all together - plumbing, "ground", everything. That would get rid of the tingle for sure, but what would that do to my meter? If there's voltage, there will be power flowing so I'm guessing I'll have to pay for it, right? That's assuming the breakers don't trip (I even have GFCI aka RCD breakers installed for safety).

Comment: @EugeneSh. Your house is likely filled with earthed appliances that have Y capacitors to earth in their mains filters, and your fuses are not blown.

Comment: @Vilx- No, you should not do that. Hire a licenced electrician that knows what needs to be done, safely and legally. In many EU countries, you are not legally allowed to do any electrical work yourself, other than install a light fixture and remove socket covers during painting or tapestry work. Some countries allow making an extension cord yourself, or fixing a mains cord with a new plug.

Comment: As far as I can tell, there is no such requirement in my country. Well, if you're building a new building then sure - there's all kinds of building codes and paperwork required. But I cannot find anything about already existing properties. That said, a professional electrician is definitely safer, no doubt about that.